# c program function chart parameter

Tags: c, function

I am new in c programming and I have a problem with my c program.
i want to pass an 10x20 chart as a parameter to a function.
But i dont know how to.

It gives me this compilation error:

```
prog.c:71:6: error: conflicting types for 'thermokrasies'
 void thermokrasies(float n[10][20]){
      ^
prog.c:2:6: note: previous declaration of 'thermokrasies' was here
 void thermokrasies(float);
      ^
```

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void temperatures(float);
int main(void) {
    float array[10][20];
    array[0][0]=3.00;
    array[0][19]=-1.50;
    array[9][0]=3.50;
    array[9][19]=-1.00;
    for (i=0; i<1; i++){
        for (j=1; j<19; j++){
            array[i][j]=2.00;
        }
    }
    for (i=9; i<10; i++){
        for (j=1; j<19; j++){
            array[i][j]=3.00;
        }
    }
    for (j=0; j<1; j++){
        for (i=1; i<9; i++){
            array[i][j]=4.00;
        }
    }
    for (j=19; j<20; j++){
        for (i=1; i<9; i++){
            array[i][j]=-5.00;
        }
    }
    for (i=1; i<9; i++){
        for (j=1; j<19; j++){
            array[i][j]=1.00;
        }
    }
    temperatures(array[10][20]);
}

void temperatures(float n[10][20]){
    int i,j;
    float h,k,m,p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10;
    h=n[0][0];
    k=n[0][0];
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        for (j=0; j<20; j++){
            if (n[i][j]>h)
                h=n[i][j];
            else if (n[i][j]<k)
                k=n[i][j];
            else{
            }
        }
    }
    printf("To megalytero stoixeio einai to %.2f kai to mikrotero to %.2f.\n",h,k);
    m=(h-k)/10;
    p0=k;
    p1=m+p0;
    p2=m+p1;
    p3=m+p2;
    p4=m+p3;
    p5=m+p4;
    p6=m+p5;
    p7=m+p6;
    p8=m+p7;
    p9=m+p8;
    p10=m+p9;
    printf("Oi perioxes 8ermokrasiwn einai: \n %.2f ews %.2f \n %.2f ews %.2f \n %.2f ews %.2f \n %.2f ews %.2f \n %.2f ews %.2f \n %.2f ews %.2f \n %.2f ews %.2f \n %.2f ews %.2f \n %.2f ews %.2f \n %.2f ews %.2f",p0,p1,p1,p2,p2,p3,p3,p4,p4,p5,p5,p6,p6,p7,p7,p8,p8,p9,p9,p10);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare at the beginning as follows:

```
void temperatures(float n[10][20]);
```

instead of

```
void temperatures(float);
```

Then call the function `void temperature(float n[10][20])` as

```
temperatures(array);
```

instead of

```
temperatures(array[10][20]);
```

Also, you have not declared variables `i` and `j` in `int main()` as

```
int i, j;
```

before using it.

Comment: thanks! it worked!! :)))